# LinkedIn OAUTH localhost fails with "Refused to get unsafe header "X-CDN"

Tags: node.js, linkedin-api

This seems to have just started this week with no code or config changes on my side - the linkedin OAUTH connect/login api breaks on my localhost node app - here is the console error on browser:

```
Refused to get unsafe header "X-CDN"
https://static.licdn.com/scds/concat/common/js?h={GIANT_HASH...}:6
```

I cannot reproduce this on a public DNS site with the same code only localhost. any clues?

Comment: I recently ran into the same issue and didn't find any answers regarding the console error. Apparently it has to do with the browser and the API itself. I ran it on Chrome and the issue persisted, but Firefox didn't have any errors.

Answer (score 0):

Visiting the linkedin directly is giving me the same error in the console. I don't think it is anything you are doing wrong, seems to be their issue.